# Read data to inner lists

Tags: python, list

In the text file, the data is:

```
#
2.1,-3.1
-0.7,4.1
#
3.8,1.5
-1.2,1.1
```

I want to read it into nested list and the list should have data in the form like:

```
[[[2.1,-3.1],[-0.7,[4.1]],[[3.8,1.5],[-1.2,1.1]]]
```

That is,
Every # starts a inner list
Every new line starts a inner list.
The next # closes previous inner list and creates new inner list.

Also The data is in string format and it needs to be converted to float values. I have written the following code:

```
def read_weights(file_name):  # 1 Mark
    file = open(file_name)
    res = []
    for line in file:
        m = []
        if '#' in line.strip():
            pass
        else:
            x = line.split()
            for i in x:
                y = i.split(',')
                i = 0
                for c in y:
                    m.insert(i, float(c))
                    i = i + 1
        if m != []:
            res .append(m)
    file.close()
    return res
w_example = read_weights('example_weights.txt')
print(w_example)
```

The output is:

```
[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1], [3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]
```

After every #, i am not been able to create a inner list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using negative indexing to access the last inserted list.

**Ex:**

```
result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
  for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "#":
      result.append([])
    else:
      line = list(map(float, line.split(",")))
      result[-1].append(line)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1]], [[3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks Alot. I was thinking about maps but was avoiding to change my code.. This code is compact and makes more sense. Also, with open (filename), need not to close the file.

Comment: def read_weights(file_name):  # 1 Mark
    file = open(file_name)
    res = []
    for line in file:
        line=line.strip();
        m=[]
        if '#' in line:
            res.append([])
        else:
            x = line.split()
            for i in x:
                y = i.split(',')
                i = 0
                for c in y:
                    m.insert(i, float(c))
                    i = i + 1
        if m != []:
            res[-1].append(m)
    file.close()
    return res

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes based on the suggestion by Mr. Rakesh
And my code works also.
**def read_weights(file_name):
file = open(file_name)
res = []
for line in file:
line=line.strip();
m=[]
if '#' in line:
res.append([])
else:
x = line.split()
for i in x:
y = i.split(',')
i = 0
for c in y:
m.insert(i, float(c))
i = i + 1
if m != []:
res[-1].append(m)
file.close()
return res**

Thank You Mr. Rakesh